# How to concatenate a number to a variable name in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, variables, numbers

I have a variable `a = 1`. I want to generate a variable name of the form:

```
variableNumber
```

So in this example, I would want

```
a1
a2
a3
```

as variables. How can I do that?

Comment: Although this is of course possible (as the answers showed already), it isn't very useful in most cases. Is there any reason why a struct or array can not be used?

Comment: Funny. I had one of my non-programming colleagues ask the same question last week. My answer was "don't". Then I showed him how he could use an array for the same purpose.

Comment: I think this should be mentioned: [How can I create variables A1, A2,...,A10 in a loop?](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `genvarname`.

```
varname = genvarname(str)
```

is the basic syntax for use. MATLAB documentation has detailed examples of using this function with an exclusion list (for ensuring unique variable names). You will have to use `eval` or another function (e.g. `assignin`, mentioned in an earlier answer) to utilise this variable name.

To answer the question completely,

```
varnamelist = genvarname({'a','a','a','a','a'});
for l=1:length(varnamelist)
  eval([varnamelist{l} '= l^2']);
end
```

Of course, there are more efficient ways of putting together an input list for `genvarname`, this is left as an exercise ;)

If you're concerned about performance, note that `eval` may slow down the script/function greatly; personally I would recommend the use of struct or cell datatypes if you need dynamic variable naming.

Comment: Use cell arrays, structures, 3D arrays or other ways to store data, but don't poof variables in the workspace.

Answer (score 19):

My answer to this question is "Are you sure you really want to do that?"

If you have a series of variables like this, you are then going to have to figure out a way to refer to all those variables later, that will likely mean an EVAL or something else like that.

If you know that everything you will store in this will be a scalar, you could store them all in a vector:

```
a(1) = 1;
a(2) = 2;
a(3) = 3;
```

What if you do not have scalars?

```
a{1} = 1;
a{2} = 'Doug';
a{3} = [1 2 3 4];
```

Then you can refer to these as a{1} or whatever.

Unless you have a good reason to do this, you are better off making a cell array, array of structures, vector, or something else.

Comment: Note that as long as all entries are numeric and guaranteed to have the same size, you should use a matrix. They are stored and handled more efficiently than cell arrays. Small example: `clear a; a(1,:,:) = rand(3); a(2,:,:) = magic(3)`

Answer (score 4):

Use `assignin`.

```
assignin('base', sprintf('variable%d', 1), 1:10)
```

---

EDIT: As JS mentioned, structs are generally better for dynamic field names.  You can use them like this:

```
varnames = {'foo', 'bar'};
str = struct;
for i = 1:length(varnames)
   str = setfield(str, varnames{i}, rand); %#ok<SFLD>
end

str =    
     foo: 0.4854
     bar: 0.8003
```

Or even more simply, like this:

```
str2.('alpha') = 123;
str2.('beta') = 1:10;
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer to this question is "Are you sure you really want to do that?"

But if your answer is YES then that is your answer:

```
for k=1:5
  eval(['a' num2str(k) '= k;'])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this code for an application with Bootstrap neural networks

```
% k fold test with automatic division of data

warning off

% read in X
% read in T

% perform k fold division of input time series called 'K-fold Cross-Validation
% Bootstrap'

CVO = cvpartition(X,'k',10); % creates 10 sub samples of 'X' and divides it into 'training (i.e training and validation)' and 'testing' sets

for i = 1:CVO.NumTestSets
    eval(['xtv' num2str(i) '=X(CVO.training(i));']) % cross-validation training sets of 'X'
    eval(['xt' num2str(i) '=X(CVO.test(i));']) % cross-validation testing set of 'X'
    eval(['ttv' num2str(i) '=T(CVO.training(i));']) % cross-validation training set of 'T'
    eval(['tt' num2str(i) '=T(CVO.test(i));']) % cross-validation testing set of 'T'
end
```