# I would like to create a loop that creates a different variable name after each iteration

Tags: matlab

I would like to create a set of distinct variables in the form of `e_1`, `e_2`, `e_3`... The number of variables would depend on the value of `k` as shown below.

```
for i = 1:k

  "create variable" = e_"i";

end
```

I will then want to call these variables; hence, I would need another loop that would be able to assign the correct value to each variable created before, or pull something out of the variable.

Comment: `eval` could do this.  But a cell array might be easier.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Using an array will do the same job, right? http://www.ele.uri.edu/Courses/ele541/tutorials/matlab.html

Comment: google it: http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate a number to a variable name in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635/how-to-concatenate-a-number-to-a-variable-name-in-matlab), http://stackoverflow.com/q/16099398

Comment: Thanks everyone, building a cell array solved the problem.

Comment: Generally it is not considered good practice in Matlab to use variables like that. **Always** consider exploiting vector, matrix, cell, struct formats!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to do something like this:

```
kk = 10;
for ii=1:kk
  eval(['e_' num2str(ii) '=[];'])
end
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, building a cell array solved all the problems

Answer (score -1):

I got just the fix for you. Was just trying to do the same thing. Needed to be able to create an array with an infinate number of variables. Here's what I came up with. Well, I was adding 2 variables at a time, so it may be a little different than your version.

```
String[] parts;
String x = "";
String var = "";
int i = 0;
//to add variables
if(x.contains("-"){
 x+="-"+var;
}
else{
x+=""+var;
}
```

then to get them, u just use.

```
if(x.contains("-")){
parts = x.split("-");
while(i<parts.length){
  var=parts[i];
  i++;
 }
}
else if (x!=""){
var = x;
}
```

Changing the variables is a whole other story. I'll let your gifted mind figure that out. I don't need that part yet.

*hint, you're going to have to loop and put together the whole String back together with the new variables. Hope this helped. Felt like this was a new way of looking at it.