# MATLAB: New variables / variable name in loop

Tags: matlab

This is probably an extremely remedial question, so I apologize in advance, however I'm pretty new to MATLAB and keep getting stumped at this simple problem.

So, I have an arbitrary matrix (D) that denotes a directed network:

```
D = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,1,1,0,0;
     0,0,0,0,1,0,0;
     0,0,0,0,0,1,0;
     0,0,0,0,0,1,0;
     0,0,0,0,0,0,1;
     0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

n = length(D);
```

All that I want to do is count the out-degree of each node. This can be calculated easily using the command:

```
O = cumsum(D,2);
O1 = (1,n);
... for all n in D...
```

I am just trying to write a loop command so that the script counts the out-degree of each node in the network and when doing so creates a new variable. I wrote the following loop command:

```
O = cumsum(D,2);
for i=1:n
    O_i = O(i,n)
end
```

However, I keep just updating the same variable 'O_i' as opposed to creating new variables, 'O_1,...,O_7' :( .

Is there any way to create a new variable for each loop??

Many thanks,

Owen

Comment: Why don't you store the results in an array?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635/how-to-concatenate-a-number-to-a-variable-name-in-matlab

Comment: This question gets asked a lot, and has nothing to do with adjacency matrices or graph-theory. See the duplicate question above, it is usually considered bad practice to define variables `a_i` in a loop, it is better to put everything in a vector and do simple indexing: `a(i)`.

Comment: Apologies for the incompetence there; thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is essentially an array, thankfully, matlab is quite good with that, you can simply use `O(i)`, but it's better to initialize first: `O=zeros(size(D,2),1)`.

that been said, in this case all you really need is the [sum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) function: `O=sum(D,2)`, here `O(i)` will be the out-degree of node `i`

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you want matlab to take "O_i" as a variable, you want to format "O_i" with "i" as the changing variable. You can use the following to make the variable name before storing it. ie

```
eval(['O' num2str(i) ' = O (' num2str(i) ', n )']) ;
```

Comment: Sorry, but nothing you wrote is valid in matlab.  Please test a line of code before you post it.